# Error calling Accounts.resetPassword

Tags: angularjs, meteor, passwords, angular-meteor

I'm using Meteor's built-in account reset behaviour which sends you an email containing a reset link and then internally calls the Accounts.resetPassword method when you click on that link. It works great on the dev machine, but on our staging server (Heroku) it returns an 'Internal Server Error' with the following stack trace:

```
Exception while invoking method 'resetPassword' Error: setUserId must be called on string or null, not object 
    at [object Object]._.extend._setUserId (livedata_server.js:774:13) 
    at [object Object].setUserId [as _setUserId] (livedata_server.js:666:14) 
    at [object Object]._.extend.setUserId (packages/ddp-common/method_invocation.js:94:1) 
    at AccountsServer.Ap._loginUser (accounts_server.js:286:20) 
    at AccountsServer.Ap._attemptLogin (accounts_server.js:340:12) 
    at AccountsServer.Ap._loginMethod (accounts_server.js:368:15) 
    at [object Object].Meteor.methods.resetPassword (password_server.js:643:19) 
    at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (livedata_server.js:1698:12) 
    at livedata_server.js:708:19 
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
```

[image]

We're not customizing the the email sent, just using the default email from Meteor. Email is sent via SendGrid.

In both cases, there is no logged in user.

Comment: Please show the js where you call `Accounts.resetPassword()` including the values you're passing.

Comment: I don't call it, I'm using the default Meteor behaviour where Meteor calls resetPassword itself

Comment: I've reworded the question to make it clearer what's happening

Comment: Try to track the data that goes over the websocket. This will at least tell you whether the issue originates in the client (sends a different argument on your staging server) or the server code.

Comment: The only difference I can see in the websockets is that the localhost request header has the following cookies in it but the Heroku version doesn't: __atuvc=5%7C14%2C51%blahblah; _ga=GA1.1.629blahblah; express.sid=s%3AP3GjI6q49hblahblah

Comment: And a Heroku proxy header on the response Via:1.1 vegur

Comment: Resolved the issue by not using the built in account reset.